# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle login form styling

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I already have register form styled (I changed some widgets by adding fields.html.twig and load it globally) but the styles won't be applied to login form elements, as the html tags are rendered here directly, not using Symfony's helpers. Should I rewrite FOS Security controller to get the form variable or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the [`SecurityController:renderLogin`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L61) action doesn't return a variable containing a `FormView` instance.

The form's HTML code (and therefore the classes you could use for styling) is hardcoded into the login template.

You have the following two options for overriding the template containing the HTML code.

## 1) override the template in app/Resources/FOSUserBundle

You can simply override the template [`FosUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig) by putting a `login.html.twig` into the folder

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/
```

Just make sure you include ...

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
```

... in your newly created template.

## 2) override the template using bundle inheritance

Another way of overriding the template would be using **bundle inheritance**.

Therefore you would create a new bundle that extends FOSUserBundle by returning `'FOSUserBundle'` in it's `getParent()` method.

```
class ExtendingBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the bundle in `app/AppKernel.php`.

Now you can store your new `login.html.twig` template at

```
 src\Vendor\ExtendingBundle\Resources\views\login.html.twig
```

## documentation

Read more about template inheritance in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc).

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it's possible and already did that to registration form. But how can I use symfony's helpers (so that it would use global styles) for login form? What's the proper way?